# Move ALL text on generated PDF page up or down specified amount in iText5 - C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, itext

I'm trying to add an option to move the text down in a PDF generated with iTextSharp 5.  Previously, users would click a button, and a PDF would be generated.  Now, I am adding an option where they click the same button, choose  Top, Middle, or Bottom, and the same PDF is generated, but with the text moved down to the middle, or close to the bottom of the page if they did not choose Top.  I already have the pop-up working, and the variable set for the if statement, I just need to find the right command in iText5 to move ALL text added to the document down based on the if statement of the Top, Middle or Bottom variable.

Here is my current code, everything is working except for the "moveText" command, which was recommended online, seems to only be supported by iText7 (I'm also not sure if that command can be used for the whole page, or needs to be pointed at specific paragraphs anyway).

```
iTextSharp.text.Document document = new 
iTextSharp.text.Document(PageSize.A4, 25, 25, 30, 30);
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, fs);
// Create an instance to the PDF file by creating an instance of the PDF 
// Writer class using the document and the filestrem in the constructor.      
// Open the document to enable you to write to the document 
document.Open();
// Set values of paragraphs
Chunk glue = new Chunk(new VerticalPositionMark());
Paragraph p1 = new Paragraph("CaseType: " + type, fontLb);
p1.Add(new Chunk(glue));
p1.Add("Date Filed: " + datefiled);
Chunk glue2 = new Chunk(new VerticalPositionMark());
Paragraph p2 = new Paragraph("Case No: " + caseno, fontLb);
p2.Add(new Chunk(glue2));
p2.Add("Amount of Suit: " + claim);
Paragraph p3 = new Paragraph("Section: " + divsec + "\n", fontLb);
p3.Alignment = Rectangle.ALIGN_LEFT;
Paragraph p4 = new Paragraph("AUSTIN BADON, CLERK", fontS);
p4.Alignment = Rectangle.ALIGN_CENTER;
Paragraph p5 = new Paragraph(caption, fontSb);
p5.Alignment = Rectangle.ALIGN_CENTER;
//Add previously defined paragraphs 
document.Add(p1); 
document.Add(p2); 
document.Add(p3); 
document.Add(p4); 
document.Add(p5); 
// Check if Middle or Bottom were selected, if so, move text down appropriate distance.
        if (btnFolderLblBot.Checked)
        {
            moveText(0, -400);
        }
        else if (btnFolderLblMid.Checked)
        {
            moveText(0, -200);            
        }
        else
        {
            moveText(0, 0);
        }
// Close the document
document.Close();
// Close the writer instance 
writer.Close();
// Always close open filehandles explicity
fs.Close();
```

The obvious expected result is that when btnFolderBot.Checked = true, the entire text of the generated PDF is shifted down to the bottom of the page, when btnFolderMid.Checked = True, the entire text of the generated PDF is shifted down to the middle of the page.  If btnFolderTop.Checked = true, or is for whatever reason not working properly, the text does not move at all.

Comment: I don't know about your `moveText` command, in particular because your use of it implies that it is a method of your class. What you could do, though, is to move the media box and crop box upwards so that the text is located more to them bottom of these boxes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I came up with (very likely not the most elegant, as I am very new to iTextSharp, and C# in general), was using the following after properly setting up the 3 check box values:

```
if (btnFolderLblBot.Checked)
        {
            document.SetMargins(40, 40, 522, 66);
        }
        else if (btnFolderLblMid.Checked)
        {
            document.SetMargins(40, 40, 306, 288);
        }
        else
        {
            document.SetMargins(40, 40, 81, 510);
        }
```

This quite simply changed the margins iTextSharp would use to place the rectangles, effectively moving it up and down.  In my case I am trying to position text to go top, middle, or bottom, to fit on an Avery label when printed, so having the rest of the page unusable is actually ideal for me.  It may not be for others looking to move text around but still be able to use the whole page for other text.